# Using Javascript to initiate onClick() events for multiple buttons on a page

Tags: javascript, html, events, download, iteration

I found a few articles on similar topics but the solutions did not work unfortunately. Forgive me if that is my error.

**Background**
I have a client who is migrating from one web based pdf document library provider to another. The current provider has no way to export all of their documents other than us going in and clicking download on each one. There is a list of all documents on a page with download buttons next to each.

I tried to use the console in Google Chrome to write a script to do this.

**Code**
All the download buttons have a similar id name structure as follows, where the number is incrementing:

id="mainForm:documentList:0:j_id_4d"
id="mainForm:documentList:1:j_id_4d"
id="mainForm:documentList:2:j_id_4d"

Here is an example button:

```
<button id="mainForm:documentList:0:j_id_4d" name="mainForm:documentList:0:j_id_4d" type="button" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only" onclick="window.open('api/internal/documents/619c342f-e006-423e-b45b-43db822bd193','_self')" role="button" aria-disabled="false"><span class="ui-button-text ui-c">Download</span></button>
```

I wrote this code to find all the buttons matching this:

```
var buttons = document.querySelectorAll('[id$="_id_4d"]');
```

I can see buttons is populated with all the correct buttons.

When I iterate through all the buttons with this loop to initiate the onclick events, only the first onclick event initiates a download. To debug, I also added an if condition inside the for loop to test if a specific index would initiate it's onclick download event(say when i is 2) and that pdf will download.

```
for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
        buttons[i].click();
}
```

I can also see in the Network console that the first file shows a status of 200 and the others say cancelled.

[Network errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OfmPD.png)

Some of the articles indicated event delegation or listening needed to be implemented which I tried but didn't work either. I am more of a power user than a programming anymore. Any insight is very appreciated.

Thank you so much in advance!
Stephan

Comment: you have an extra } there.. also try `buttons.forEach(button => { button.click(); });` a one-liner instead of a for loop

Comment: Thank you @astigmatik for your suggestion. I changed that but it still only downloads one file. Hmmm. Thoughts?

Comment: oh.. it's the _self that's breaking it in the window.open().. I think you have to change it for every button

Comment: @astigmatik do you have any suggestions how to do that programmatically? Also I just looked in the Network console and can see that the first call that downloads gets a 200 OK then the others say cancelled. I added an image to the original post for this!

Comment: @astigmatik when I went in and deleted the _self entries in the window.open() on a few of the buttons the file download worked on those after I ran the script. You are a genius. The issue is this is not my page and I will need to do this manually hundreds of times to get all the files LOL. I wonder if I can remove "_self" in the foreach loop of each call?

Comment: @astigmatik ok I'm just using the search and replace in the console like this first: 

```
document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(/_self/g, "")
```
to remove the _self then run your suggestion and it works. 

You are amazing. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The issue was the "_self" in the window.open() of the buttons.

When I removed those all reference to _self the files downloaded perfectly.

Thank You astigmatik!

Answer (score 0):

You can get all buttons using this selector:

```
var buttons=document.querySelectorAll('[id^="mainForm:documentList:"][id$=":j_id_4d"]');
```

and loop through them using **`forEach()`**

Then call click for every item in list

Final code is something like this:

```
var buttons=document.querySelectorAll('[id^="mainForm:documentList:"][id$=":j_id_4d"]');
    
buttons.forEach(function(button){
    console.log(button);
    button.click();
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. It still only downloads 1 file. I added some additional comments above about seeing the other file downloads cancelled. A suggestion was made that the _self on the window.open was the issue. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Yes every button should open a separate tab or window. Don't use _self.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a guess. `window.open()` is often blocked when it's not coming from a user action because the browser might think that it's some kind of pop-up scam. I tried this simple program in my browser:

```
<button onclick="clicked()">click me</button>
<button onclick="clicked()">click me</button>
<button onclick="clicked()">click me</button>
<button onclick="clicked()">click me</button>
<button onclick="clicked()">click me</button>
<button onclick="clicked()">click me</button>


<script>
  function clicked() {
    window.open('https://google.com', '_blank')
  }
  const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button'); 
  buttons.forEach(button => button.click())
</script>
```

And it woul not work correctly. However, if I changed the settings in my browser (chrome) to allow pop-ups, then everything worked as expected.

You might want to give it a try